# Increase Max pods per node with advanced networking on AKS

Tags: azure-container-service

we have created our Kubernetes cluster with Advanced Networking via the Azure Management UI.

Some time later we've run into the limitation of pods per node described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/aks/container-service-quotas

We need to change the limitation of 30 pods per node as it is very incomprehensible one for us. Before the advanced networking was possible at all, there was no such limitation and it was also undocumented at the moment, we've created the cluster. Could someone help, how to do change the max pods amount without recreation the whole cluster?

Regards, Gena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the max number of pods per node on an existing cluster

https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/aks/networking-overview#configure-maximum---existing-clusters

You will need to redeploy a new cluster and specify the new max number during provisioning.

Comment: Hello Micah and thank you for your answer! I'm not very satisfied with it. The limitation is not a natural one but introduced by microsoft. We've used previously a cluster with basic networking (as the advanced networking was not available) with smaller machines and didn't have the limitation.

Comment: Yeah understood. Unfortunately that is the limitation that was put in place and until the product team implements an actual work around or improves the limitation of advance networking then redeploy is the option :/ You can leave feedback for product improvements here just as an FYI. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but with different solution.
As of June 2021 there is no need to redeploy the cluster - we can add a new node pool with required pods to node ratio.

The dialog box allows us to set new values and then we can use node labels to redirect pods or just shut down previous pool.

[image: New node configuration]

Answer (score 3):

No one mentionned it so I will
Be careful if you are using Azure CNI and want to set a high max-pods per node
Azure CNI will reserve the number of IP per node in your subnet, so this value should be calculated to avoid facing IP exhaustion issues
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `nodepool` and set `max-pods`:

```
az aks nodepool add --name mypool --node-vm-size Standard_E4s_v3 --node-count 1 -g AKS-resource-name --cluster-name cluster-name --max-pods 100
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest